Prevent browser back button from going to previous page for MUI modal/dialog in new NextJS approuter
I am using MUI, typescript, nextjs, with the new approuter.
I would like to hijack the browser's back button behavior when the modal is open, so that it would close the modal instead of going to previous page in the browser, this is the intuitive behavior for mobile users.
Please use this simplified boilerplate to avoid complexity:
"use client"
import { Modal } from '@mui/material'
import { useState } from 'react'

export default function Component() {
    const [open, setOpen] = useState(false)

    return (
        <>
            <Modal
                open={open}
                onClose={() => setOpen(false)}
                style={{ display: "flex", alignItems: "center", justifyContent: "center" }}
            >
                <div style={{ background: "white", padding: "100px" }}>
                    hi
                </div>
            </Modal>
            
            <button onClick={() => setOpen(true)}>
                open modal
            </button>
        </>
    )
}


You need contextual routing
Here is an example by vercel themselves
Source code:
https://github.com/vercel/nextgram?tab=readme-ov-file
Demo app:
https://nextgram.vercel.app/
Official docs on this:
https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/intercepting-routes
parallel and intercepting routes are new features they added specifically for contextual routing
You will need to

Create a modal route that intercepts your original route



Instead of opening your modal with state - navigate to the same route with Link on the client

// code inside of .../photo/id 

export default function YourPage() {
  return (
   <div>
     <nav>whatever</nav>
     <div>whatever</div>
     <Link href="/photo/id">
       open modal
     </Link>

   </div>
  )
}

and this will open the route on
.../@modal/photo/id

and if you refresh the page you will get your original /photo/id page

1st article is old and your 2nd article is for pagesrouter, also please provide a complete example

here is an example by vercel themselves
Source code:
https://github.com/vercel/nextgram?tab=readme-ov-file
Demo app:
https://nextgram.vercel.app/
you can read more about whats going here:
https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/intercepting-routes
parallel and intercepting routes are new features they added specifically for contextual routing

Links are liable to die or change, making an answer that depends solely on them useless. Please provide an example in the answer.

I dont think copy-pasting the official docs is useful too, next.js and app router are liable to die or change the same way the links are.
A complete answer and an example would require me to whip up a whole repo for that, there is a repo demonstrating the desired functionality by the official team already.

their repo is not desirable, when the page has a scroll, when ure not at the very top then opening their modal jumps the scroll position to the top of the page which is very ugly behavior, which makes their repo completely useless
